# GCC - exact location of type declaration

Tags: c++, gcc, crash, segmentation-fault, libuv

I have a C++ code which depends on [libuv](http://github.com/joyent/libuv) library (C code). It's crashing because of the segfault. I narrowed down the problem: [libuv](http://github.com/joyent/libuv) uses `struct stat` from `<sys/stat.h>`. If I print size of this struct in my code:

```
printf("struct stat size: %d\n", sizeof(struct stat));
```

it shows 88. If I print the same in libuv library, it shows 96. This is the cause of the segfault. I am a bit stuck here. How can I find exact location of type declaration? Any other approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that is the cause? Have you tried running your program in a debugger and examining the call stack? You should do that first.

Comment: Did you build `libuv` yourself or are you using a precompiled binary?

Comment: While it is not uncommon for struct stat having different size depending on certain posix features enabled, it usually is of no issue if you pass around such a struct only within code that uses the same definition. So if you don't exchange such a struct with libuv, then the culprit is likely elsewhere. And if you do, you should have set the same defines as them (better yet would be that they set the correct defines, which might work if you include their header first)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, yes, it's part of another struct - uv_fs_t; memory for uv_fs_t is allocated in my code and the struct itself is used in libuv; valgrind gives errors when libuv is trying to access fields declared after the field of type struct stat.

Comment: @MarkB, I built it myself.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, I think you are right. All such defines should be in the library header which I include anyway. The question is how can I find those defines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could preprocess the source with `cc -E xxx.c`, and look for the offending definition in there. The `#file` and `#line` directives in the preprocessed `xxx.i` will point you to the approximate position of the culprit. Or just `#include <sys/stat.h>` at the very beginning (before any stuff from the library), the compiler should scream at you for redefining the `struct` ;-)